# rewrite from index.php?.... to index.php%3F....html

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, wget

I'm trying to make static a b2evolution site with this wget line:

```
  wget -nv -b -m -k -p -E -erobots=off --tries=5 --exclude-directories=calendar,users,user --domains directory http://site.com
```

It produce file like this:

```
  index.php?blog=2&cat=21.html
```

Trying to visit this url at:

```
  http://site.com/index.php?blog=2&cat=21.html
```

i recive this error on browser:

```
  Not Found
  The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.
```

and this on error.log:

```
  [Mon Feb 10 19:02:49 2013] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] script '/var/www/site.com/htdocs/index.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: http://site.com/index.php
```

but i can access using %3F instead '?':

```
  http://site.com/index.php%3Fblog=2&cat=21.html
```

My scope is permit the access to the site with the old type of url (with '?') using apache rewrite_mod to modify '?' with '%3F'. I have tryed with:

```
  RewriteRule ^index.php\? index.php\%3F [QSA,NE]
```

but i recive this error on log:

```
  Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

Any idea to solve with mod_rewrite or with others wget arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following rule should work if the filenames contain `?`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.+)
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)$ $1\%3F%1 [L]
```

It works as follows:

- `RewriteRule` is evaluated ***first***, matches get stored in $0, $1, ...
- Upon success, `RewriteCond` is evaluated and matches get stored in %0, %1, ...
- Finally, the two matches are combined
- The literal `%` character is escaped as `\%` (necessary since `%n` is used for RewriteCond back-references)
- `%3F` is the URL encoded form of `?` which otherwise denotes beginning of query string
- `.+` is used to match non-empty query string

Comment: It works. Let me undestand.. with the Cond you get any query with 0 or more char that later we can use with %i (i=1 in this case). Than you catch between () the $1 arg. The dot inside must be protected because it means any char. At the end we tell to the mod_rewrite how to trasform the recived url.

Answer (score 0):

See the --restrict-file-names option. While not exactly intended for this particular purpose, --restrict-file-names=windows will probably help you along:

> --restrict-file-names=modes
>
> Change which characters found in remote URLs must be escaped during
>   generation of local filenames. [...]
>
> When "windows" is given, Wget escapes the characters \, |, /, :, ?, ",
>   *, <, >, and the control characters in the ranges 0--31 and 128--159. In addition to this, Wget in Windows mode uses + instead of : to
>   separate host and port in local file names, and uses @ instead of ? to
>   separate the query portion of the file name from the rest. Therefore,
>   a URL that would be saved as www.xemacs.org:4300/search.pl?input=blah
>   in Unix mode would be saved as
>   www.xemacs.org+4300/search.pl@input=blah in Windows mode.